# Assigning to an optional reference parameter

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, default-parameters

Say we have define a function that takes a reference paramter which will contain an error message, but we don't always need the error message, so we allow that reference parameter to be omitted:

```
function isSpider($bug, &$errorMsg = null) {

    if(gettype($bug) !== "object") {
        $errorMsg = "An error occurred: bug must be an object";
        return false;
    }
    return $bug->species === "spider";

}
```

When we omit the reference parameter, is `$errorMsg` just a local variable? I tried assigning to it like in the example above and it produced no error messages with `E_ALL` on. It seems strange that you can assign a default value to a variable that is a reference to nothing. It's useful, but I just want to make sure I understand the intended behavior. The PHP docs are skimpy on this.

The two use cases that the optional reference parameter permits:

```
// we want to print the error message
if(!isSpider($bug1, $errorMsg)) echo $errorMsg;
```

or:

```
// don't care about the error message
if(isSpider($bug)) doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its better use [try-catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) to do error in your case.

```
function isSpider($bug, $alarm=TRUE) {
    if (gettype($bug) !== "object") {
         if ($alarm === TRUE) {
             throw new Exception("An error occurred: bug must be an object");
         }
         return false;
    }
    return $bug->species === "spider";
}
```

If you want to print the error message:

```
try {
    if (isSpider($bug1)) {
        // do something
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "We have an error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

If you want to store the error message for later use:

```
$errorMsg = FALSE;
try {
    if (isSpider($bug1)) {
        // do something
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
}

if ($errorMsg != FALSE) {
    // do something with the error message
}
```

And if you want to ignore the message

```
// silent mode
if (isSpider($bug, FALSE)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: > "You cannot omit a reference parameter in function." This is not true. From [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php): "Note: As of PHP 5, arguments that are passed by reference may have a default value."

Comment: Wow! I didn't know the PHP5 change. Thanks :-)

Comment: My method does not "prevent being able to store the error message". I've updated my answer to show how you could do it.

Comment: Np. It's only mentioned once briefly in the docs so I wouldn't be surprised if a bunch of people don't know about it.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I misunderstood your example the first time. Thanks for the update. [Removed my previous comment by accident.]